# Running the node-express app live in render.com with query throws internal server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, render.com

I'm trying to run a route live with query using `nodejs express` app in `render.com`. All other routes related to the crud operations are getting executed except the search filter route `url with the query`. I'm getting the below error while running it in `render.com`

[image: browser_error_screen]

I'm passing this parameter correctly in my live url => **https://stackoverflow-demo-nodejs-express-s.onrender.com/sd-db-1021/collections/products/?quer=hi**, but its throwing the internal server error. If you check the **https://stackoverflow-demo-nodejs-express-s.onrender.com/sd-db-1021/collections/products/**, it would give the response for the same router.get method implemented in the storage.js file.

Moreover, the operation is getting executed with `localhost`. Below is the reference:

[image]

I'm unable to debug this issue. Any help regarding the issue would be appreciated.

Here's my piece of code:

```
/* app.js */
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create express app
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const cors = require('cors');

// set middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

// import routes
const routes = require('./routes/Routes');
app.use('/', routes);

//start server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port: ${port}`);
});


/* storage.js */
storageRoutes.get(storageUrl, (req, res) => {
    const { type } = req.params;
    const { quer } = req.query;
    // get existing data collection// fetch the collection from the storage related to the products
    let existingDataCollection = getData(storagePath);
    // get the existing data-set fot the specific type
    let existingCollectionTypeData = [...existingDataCollection[type]];

    // search filter implementation based on query
    if (quer) {
        // filter query
        const query = quer.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");
        // get the data-object related to the specified type
        existingCollectionTypeData = existingCollectionTypeData.filter((element) =>
            element.name.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
    }

    // send the response with the collection of specified types
    res.send(existingCollectionTypeData);
});
```

Comment: Very strange. Which is the node version on Render? Is it different from yours?

Comment: @pierpy Thanks a lot for the comment. The issue was render.com is using the `node version 14.17.0` and the node version I was using is `18.16.1`. The issue is resolved and I have posted the solution down below.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally,** `I got the issue resolved`.

Firstly, Thanks a lot @pierpy. I found the solution after taking your comment a bit serious.

The issue is => `render.com` is using the node version `14.17.0` and the node version I was using was `18.16.1`.

Identified from the logs:

[image]

Hence, my query implementation which had the below code was getting failed because the `node version 14.17.0` was not able to recognize `.replaceAll(" ", "")` from the below code, because in the node version `14.17.0` the implementation of `.replaceAll` might not be present:

```
// search filter implementation based on query
if (quer) {
    // filter query
    const query = quer.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");
    // get the data-object related to the specified type
    existingCollectionTypeData = existingCollectionTypeData.filter((element) =>
        element.name.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase().includes(query)
    );
}
```

Hence I followed the below steps to get to the solution:

1. Removed the => `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` with the help of
   `rm -rf <folder/filename>` command (applicable for `git bash` in windows)
2. Downgraded the node version to `14.17.0`
3. `npm install`
4. replaced => `.replaceAll(" ", "")` with `replace(/\s/g,'')`
5. pushed the code and deployed the repo back.

If any of you have encountered the same issue with `render.com` by deploying the `node-express` app, you can consider this approach and get rid of the issue.

Comment: Ok, resolved. For a similar problem I had to refactor a lot of code, to match  the "old" URL object